# What's the difference between "Would you like to go on a long drive with me?" and "Would you like to go with me on a long drive?"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, interrogatives

- Would you like to go on a long drive with me?
- Would you like to go with me on a long drive?

The position of "with me" is different in both of the above interrogative sentences.

As per my understanding both are correct but I am not sure so needed an expert advice.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is a slight difference in emphasis. And it isn't even clear which way that emphasis is pointing.

"A long drive with me" puts the long drive first, and so the person being asked is to think about the long drive first and the "with me" after.

"With me on a long drive" puts the the "with me" first. And so the person being asked is going to think about that first.

However, in some cultures, the thing held up first is going to be perceived as the important thing. And in other cultures the other way around. Even person-to-person the first thing may be thought of as more important or less important. Some people let their dog run in front, some make Rover follow behind.